# SELECT latest date in a group of results distinctly

Tags: mysql

I have a query (I show this below) generating the following result set (this goes on for 53,000 more records)

```
+--------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| emp_no | counter | emp_no | salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+--------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  60117 | 1986-06-26 | 1987-06-26 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  62102 | 1987-06-26 | 1988-06-25 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  66074 | 1988-06-25 | 1989-06-25 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  84917 | 1999-06-23 | 2000-06-22 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  85112 | 2000-06-22 | 2001-06-22 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  85097 | 2001-06-22 | 2002-06-22 |
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  88958 | 2002-06-22 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  65828 | 1996-08-03 | 1997-08-03 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  65909 | 1997-08-03 | 1998-08-03 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  67534 | 1998-08-03 | 1999-08-03 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  69366 | 1999-08-03 | 2000-08-02 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  71963 | 2000-08-02 | 2001-08-02 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  72527 | 2001-08-02 | 9999-01-01 |
...
```

Where employee number X can have multiple salaries stored, the query I'm using to fetch this set is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dept_emp.emp_no, @counter := @counter+1 AS counter 
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, dept_emp) 
AS employeeFilter 
LEFT JOIN(salaries) 
ON (salaries.emp_no = employeeFilter.emp_no) 
WHERE counter <= (25/100 * @counter) LIMIT 100;
```

I'm looking to get a single row for each unique emp_no, the most recent salary row (based on `to_date` field).

```
+--------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
| emp_no | counter | emp_no | salary | from_date  | to_date    |
+--------+---------+--------+--------+------------+------------+
|  10001 |       1 |  10001 |  88958 | 2002-06-22 | 9999-01-01 |
|  10002 |       2 |  10002 |  72527 | 2001-08-02 | 9999-01-01 |
```

The `@counter` implementation isn't really important to this issue, but it does need to remain in that query, as I'm looking to eventually build a query that will generate the cost of cutting 25% of a department, and the `@counter` variable allows me limit results by a percentage.

Tried to use DISTINCT `select DISTINCT (emp_no)` but I'm not the best with stuff like this, and that just caused more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN to make the same logic that ROW_NUMBER does like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*,count(*) as rnk
    FROM (YourQuery/table) t
    INNER JOIN (YourQuery/table) s
    ON (t.emp_no = s.emp_no AND t.from_date <= s.from_date))
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Or with a correlated query :

```
SELECT * FROM (YourQuery) t
WHERE from_date = (select max(s.from_date) 
                   FROM (YourQuery) s
                   WHERE s.emp_no = t.emp_no)
```

Comment: I can't see that first one working (but maybe I'm missing something). The second solution will scale poorly.

Comment: @Strawberry I had a typo with the > changed to < , is that what you meant? other than that I don't see why it won't work..

Comment: Well, it has a missing alias on the derived table. But assuming you fix that, does it work? Erm, no.

Answer (score 1):

Use this statement by appending a subquery with aggregate function(MAX).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dept_emp.emp_no, @counter := @counter+1 AS counter 
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, dept_emp) 
AS employeeFilter 
LEFT JOIN(salaries) 
ON (salaries.emp_no = employeeFilter.emp_no) 
WHERE counter <= (25/100 * @counter) AND
    (salaries.emp_no, salaries.to_date) IN 
        (SELECT sal.emp_no, MAX(sal.to_date) 
         FROM salaries sal
         WHERE sal.emp_no = salaries.emp_no)
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM salaries x 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT emp_no
            , MAX(to_date) max_to_date 
         FROM salaries 
        GROUP 
           BY emp_no
     ) y
    ON y.emp_no = x.emp_no 
   AND y.max_to_date = x.to_date;
```